# Undeclared field in inherited type compiling Nimrod program

Tags: inheritance, compiler-errors, nim-lang

I try to compile the following code:

```
type
  TPerson = object of TObject
    name*: string 
    age: int

  TStudent = object of TPerson
    id: int

var
  student: TStudent
  person: TPerson

student = TStudent(name: "Anton", age: 5, id: 2)
```

but I get the following error:

> Error: undeclared field: 'id'

How is `id` not declared? The code sample is straight from the tutorial. Did something in the language change that is not reflected in the tutorial?

---

Also, if I try to run the following code:

```
student = TStudent(name: "Anton")
echo student.name
```

I get the following error:

> SIGSEGV: Illegal storage access. (Attempt to read from nil?)

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you are likely using the last stable release of [Nimrod](http://nimrod-code.org) (version 0.9.2 was released in May 2013) or an old git checkout, what you highlight are bugs in the compiler. Right now with git version https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod/commit/75ca6eb34fbc983d88961664fd1cfce5f8b44abf both your first and last example work without problems. In the past months several bugs have been fixed related to object inheritance in the language ([issue 179](https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod/issues/179), [issue 520](https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod/issues/520), [issue 575](https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod/issues/575) and [issue 563](https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod/issues/563)).

If you decide to build yourself a git version (it's not scary at all, though sometimes there are regressions in the language) please [use the build instructions from the git](https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod#compiling) since the website might not have been updated yet.

Comment: Found someone with the same problem on the [nimrod forums](http://forum.nimrod-code.org/t/285)